# Woocommerce hide address fields on checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I have a tricky client who wants to hide customer address fields from his users on the woocommerce checkout page.

Address fields that need to be hidden but posted:

[image: Screenshot]

Unfortunately, I need the user address posted and appended to the order. My backend automation process relies on an address coming in with the order. The address is always the same so the content is not important.

I have been looking for a hook or filter that can sort this out, but to no avail.

Any help would be saving many bacons.

Comment: Add css to your style.css which hide and insert address of your customer.

    #billing_address_1_field{display:none;}
    #billing_address_2_field{display:none;}
    #billing_postcode_field{display:none;}

Comment: Hi Ash thanks for the suggestion, display: none did not work. I might try visibility hidden to see if that works.

Comment: That did not work either. I have done a bit of a hack and done an old school css trick position: absolute and left: 90000px; It has hidden it but post testing is all over the place. Hmmm curiouser and curiouser.

Answer (score 0):

If the address is always the same I'd suggest using JavaScripts hide function on whichever of those inputs you need hidden, and then hard coding the address prior to back end processes starting.

So instead of retrieving them via `$POST` - you could set the values at that point.

This is a basic example of the jQuery hide functionality that you could use on page load.

Alternatively do you have access to the input boxes on the form? Could you not use `<input type="hidden" value="hardcoded value"></input>`

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Would either of these work for you?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the form uses wc_something as a hook to parse the data on the form. Not all fields have a direct input tag, not unless I am missing something, in which case hidden input is the one. I will give jquery hide a go, but would that still retain the values if I have hidden those fields from the form?

Comment: Hi yes they retain the same values, there still on the page, they just don't show up for a user. So you should be fine with passing your data through like that